# Proving uniform continuity for $x/(1+x)$ on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, solution-verification

I want to show that $f(x) = x/(1+x)$ is uniform continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

My proof: Let $x,y$ be real numbers in $[0, \infty)$ and let $\epsilon$ be a positive number.

We choose $\delta = \epsilon$ such that $|y-x| < \delta = \epsilon$.

So, we have

$$ |f(x) - f(y)|\,\, =\,\, |y/(1+y) - x/(1+x)|\,\,
 =\,\, \left|\frac{y-x}{(1+y)\cdot(1+x)}\right|. $$

We note $(1+y)(1+x) \ge 1$, so 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| < |y - x| < \epsilon.$$
Thus, $f(x)$ is uniform continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct!

Comment: The proof seems fine. There were a couple of parentheses missing but the fractional line notation avoids such a nuisance (or nuance :) ).

Comment: It seems a pretty good proof.